# JPA DAO pattern doesn't commit

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I have the next configuration in a 'Standalone Java SWING application'. 
I have the problem: my service runs without errors, execute the DAO delete method, but doesn't commit the delete:

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="springappPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-      3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="gestionclinicaecocitas">
</context:component-scan>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="username"  value="${jdbc.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
<property name="loadTimeWeaver">
<bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
</property>
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="springappPU"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
p:database="${jpa.database}"
p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>
```

In the main() of my project, initialize the spring context, and get a 'service' loader class:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  ac= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
ac.getBean(SpringServiceLoader.class);
```

My SpringServiceLoader:

```
@Service
public class SpringServiceLoader{

    @Autowired
    private CalendarService calendarService;
```

The method of my serviceInterface marked as @Transactional

```
public interface CalendarioService {
@Transactional
    public void deleteDays();
}
```

The implementation of the service calling dao delete method

```
@Service("calendarService")
public class CalendarioServiceImpl implements CalendarioService{


@Autowired
private DaysDaoImpl daysDao;

@Override
public void deleteDays{
        daysDao.deleteById(1);
}

}
```

And finally the Dao structure:

```
@Repository
public class DaysDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl< Days > {

public DaysDaoImpl(){
  setClazz(Days.class );
}
```

GenericDao class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public abstract class GenericDaoImpl< T extends Serializable> {//implements GenericDao<T>{

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
private Class< T > clazz;


public void setClazz( Class< T > clazzToSet ){
   this.clazz = clazzToSet;
}

(.....)   

public void deleteById( Long entityId ){
    this.em.remove(this.em.getReference(clazz, entityId));

}
}
```

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="calendar_days")
public class Days implements java.io.Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private DaysId id;

(....)
```

I've also tryed an HQL query instead of calling a basic CRUD method and I get the error:

TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

```
 Query query = this.em
            .createQuery("delete from Days d where d.id.date < :fecha");
    query.setParameter("fecha", fecha);
    query.executeUpdate();
```

If I try to get the em transaction to make a begin/commit manually, the error changes to:

Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you move the `@Transactional` annotation from the interface to `CalendarioServiceImpl`?

Comment: Nothing, I think i have some erros in configuration, because @Transacional doesn't work in any class. I've tried to put the annotation in the DAO and in the ServiceImpl but the behaviour is the same

Comment: Post the code that is actually invoking the `deleteDays` method (or other transactional method). Small suggestion, instead of reinventing the wheel with your `GenericDao` use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
T entity = em.find(persistentClass, id);
```

to get the entity. And then call

```
em.remove(entity);
```

Or shorten this record in one line.

UPDATE (thanks to @M.Deinum)

Comment: The service layer and not the dao layer should be the transactional boundary. So don't put the annotation on the dao.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. 
The interface of the CalendarService marked as @Transactional works, the problem was that both SpringServiceLoader and CalendarService were defined as @Service.

I have rename the CalendarService to @Component stereotype, that is autowired to SpringServiceLoader marked as @Service stereotype, and now the transactions works fine automatically.

Thanks everybody for the support!
I'll take a look to Spring Data

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way to fix this is add `@Transactional` to you main() method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem is that my main() method class is outside the spring context, because is a SWING app. ¿Could I set as @Transactional a class that is not a spring managed bean?

Comment: @user3179334 ohh, so you need to move the annonation `@Transactional` from method to the `CalendarioService` instead